# Duplicate strings in a list not removed unless the most similar ones are in a sublist

Tags: python, string, nlp, duplicates

A list containing text strings (fulltexts of newspaper articles) cannot be successfully deduplicated. The only solution is to find the most common sentences, select list items containing these sentences, and then do the deduplication at the level of these sublists.

After reading through the myriad of similar questions here, I still have no solution.

Here are four different methods that I have tried:

```py
1] x = list(dict.fromkeys(lst))
2] x = set(lst)
3] from iteration_utilities import unique_everseen
   x = list(unique_everseen(lst))
4] using pandas
   df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['article_body'], keep='first')
```

All these return the same amount of list items.

However, when I check frequency distribution of the most common 'sentences' and search for one. I still find around 45 hits as this sentence appears in several texts, some of them being identical. when these texts are all lumped into one list, I can them use the x = list(dict.fromkeys(lst)). This results in only 9 list items.

How is this possible?

```py
df = pd.read_json('UK data/2010-11.json')
len(df)
13288

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['article_body'], keep='first')
len(df)
6118

lst = df['article_body'].tolist()
len(lst)
6118

# taking this solution as a reference point, here it returns 6118 at the level
# of the whole list

len(list(dict.fromkeys(lst)))
6118

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

searchStr = 'Lines close at midnight.'
found = []

for text in lst:
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    for sentence in sentences:
        if sentence == searchStr:
            found.append(text)

len(found)
45

# when the function is used only on a subset of the full-texts, it can suddenly 
# identify more duplicates

len(list(dict.fromkeys(found)))
9
```

EDIT: Please check the full demonstration in jupyter notebook available here: 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EF6PL8aduZIO--Ok0hGMzLWFIquz6F_L

I would expect that using the very same function on the full list would result in removing ALL duplicates, but this is clearly not the case. Why cannot I remove the duplicates from the whole list? How can I assure that each list item is compared with all the others?

Comment: have you taken care of various whitespace characters in your sentences ? there's like 10 different characters that look the same. Also your first sentence says "cannot be successfully deduplicated" but you want to deduplicate them ? How is that possible ?

Comment: I didnt. Here I am only interested in how come that duplicates can be recognised in a list of 45 items, but not in the list of 6118 items. Besides turning pandas series into the list, I didnt preprocess the strings. Note that what ends up in the "found" is the full texts, not the sentences.

Comment: Whitespaces are like spaces, tabs, newlines and the like. There are special spaces (non-breaking space or zero-width space) in web design so it is very likely that you are getting different results because the functions don't treat whitespaces the same - some may conserve them, other may convert them to the non-special ones. A non-breaking space is different from a space just like *a* is different from *b*.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! What I still dont get is how come that the very same function processes the whitespaces differently based on the list length? Is there any way how to control for this in order to conclude that there is this "glitch" based on dataset size?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like whitespace may be the issue.

```py
import re

x = list(set(map(lambda string: re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', string), lst)))
```

or something like it may work.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking time to answer!  I intentionally do not preprocess the data beyond deduplication at the dataset level. If I only convert pandas series into a list, how does this operation change whitespaces?

Comment: I have just tested the proposed solution and while it removes two additional duplicates, the rest unfortunately remains unaffected.